# Memcached required in Google App Engine Standard and PHP 5.5

Tags: php, symfony, google-app-engine, memcached, symfony-2.8

I have a website that I want to migrate from a classic server to a Google App Engine Standard environment. It's a PHP code, using Symfony 2.8.

I choose the Standard App Engine with **PHP 5.5** and deploy my app following this tutorial https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/symfony-hello-world-app-engine

My problem is that I have this error "Memcached >= 2.2.0 is required" and that's weird because regarding to this documentation https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/runtime?hl=fr memcached extension is already activated.

The other thing that is weird it's that when I try to use the Google Cloud Console Cloud Shell and then I try "php -v" the output is php 7.2 no matter what I have in the app.yaml an obviously when I try "php -m" there no memcached extension enabled.

I tried to add a php.ini file with memcached extension but this doesn't work and throw me an error.

How can I enable the memcached extension?

Here is my app.yaml

```
runtime: php55
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
# tell appengine where our static assets live
- url: /bundles
  static_dir: web/bundles

# the symfony front controller
- url: /.*
  script: web/app.php

# [START env_vars]
env_variables:
  SYMFONY_ENV: prod
# [END env_vars]

skip_files:
# Do not deploy bundle tests
  - (.*/)?Tests\/(.*)
  - (.*/)?.git/(.*)
```

Comment: You sure you have Memcached and not Memcache (note the 'd' at the end) installed?

Comment: Actually I am not sure because regarding to the doc both memcache and memcached are installed and enabled for php 5.5 but it doesn't work so I suspect the documentation is not up to date and I don't know how to enabled memcached by my self

Answer (score 0):

The [Google Cloud Shell](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/features) is an isolated shell environment. Any package version you directly install there, is never installed in any of the GCP services, including GAE. It always has the PHP version 7.2 without Memcached extension, hence you're seeing it displayed.

Comment: Hum I didn't know about that, so what's the purpose of this shell and why can I have a different shell by project?

Comment: As per the documentation, Cloud Shell makes it easy for you to manage your projects and resources without having to install the Google Cloud SDK and other tools on your system.